# Shortcodes not working in an AJAX call

Tags: shortcode, ajax

I am using AJAX to load next set of posts on homepage. The posts load fine but the shortcodes are not rendered. I am trying to use the do_shortcode function on the content the ajax call fetches (although experts have suggested [not to use do_shortcode](https://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-do_shortcode/)) but apparently it is failing.

Here's my function that processes the request:

```
function theme_load_more_posts() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'theme-load-more-posts-nonce', 'nonce' );

    $args = isset( $_POST['query'] ) ? array_map( 'esc_attr', $_POST['query'] ) : array();
    $args['post_type'] = isset( $args['post_type'] ) ? esc_attr( $args['post_type'] ) : 'post';
    $args['paged'] = esc_attr( $_POST['page'] );
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    ob_start();
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $loop->have_posts() ): while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
        get_content_template();
    endwhile; 
    endif;
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( do_shortcode($data) ); // Performing do_shortcode here but it doesn't work.
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_theme_load_more_posts', 'theme_load_more_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_load_more_posts', 'theme_load_more_posts' );
```

The `get_content_template()` function loads a template file that contains the regular wordpress code for displaying post contents.

I tried using `do_shortcode_in_html()` on `get_content_template()` but it doesn't work either.

I also saw similar threads related to this but they mostly addressed issues with the ajax call itself. I believe my problem lies within this function. Any guesses?

Comment: Have you tried setting your `$variable = do_shortcode($data)` to a variable first an then sending that `$variable` to `wp_send_json_success( $variable );`?

Comment: @NathanPowell I did try that but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have to also mention the `ob_get_clean();` as well. The echo could be mucking things up. I am stabbing in the dark obviously, but that looks like slop.

Comment: @NathanPowell Maybe. But no solution seems to be in sight as of now. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Maybe? Have you tried a `return` of values for the JavaScript response?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand. I did a console.log of the javascript response though and its seemed fine. It had the post template with unresolved shortcodes.

Comment: `$data = ob_get_clean();` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Try wrapping the response like `apply_filters('the_ content, $data)`.

Comment: Tried apply_filters before the do_shortcode but no luck.

Comment: I think your code is called before the shortcodes are there, like trying to get `wp` things from `init` hook..

Comment: @SamuelElh If that's the case, shouldn't it throw error of some sort? The rest of the content loads just fine.

Comment: No errors. While a short code is not ready, it will be considered as a string and parsed as is.

Comment: @SamuelElh I tried changing the priority of the add_action to execute at a later stage. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you are not calling `do_shortcode()` in the output buffer. You don't need to be running the loop within the output buffer since I can assume `get_content_template()` simply returns HTML with embedded shortcodes. Save that to a string variable, then run that through the `do_shortcode()` and save the `echo`ed output to the buffer.

This is untested but should steer you in the right direction:

```
function theme_load_more_posts() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'theme-load-more-posts-nonce', 'nonce' );

    $args = isset( $_POST['query'] ) ? array_map( 'esc_attr', $_POST['query'] ) : array();
    $args['post_type'] = isset( $args['post_type'] ) ? esc_attr( $args['post_type'] ) : 'post';
    $args['paged'] = esc_attr( $_POST['page'] );
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    $loopContent = '';
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $loop->have_posts() ): 
        while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
            $loopContent .= get_content_template();
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    ob_start();
    echo do_shortcode($loopContent);
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( $data ); // Performing do_shortcode here but it doesn't work.
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_theme_load_more_posts', 'theme_load_more_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_load_more_posts', 'theme_load_more_posts' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I tried your suggestion but the shortcodes are still not rendered. :(